# Find and replace string text between two other string texts JS

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to find and replace a word in a string

Example:

```
let string = 
`
Title: Hello World
Authors: Michael Dan
`
```

I need to find the `Hellow World` and replace with whatever I want, here is my attempt:

```
const replace = string.match(new RegExp("Title:" + "(.*)" + "Authors:")).replace("Test")
```

Comment: When you `replace()`, you do not need to `match()`. `string.replace(/(Title:).*(?=\nAuthors:)/gs, '$1Test')` can be used here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew problem, it doesn't even find the match

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you please elaborate on that? Sorry, don't quite catch it.

Comment: Ok, I see I might be wrong with the `s` flag. Anyway, you need to keep the first and last words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you replace some text, it is not necessary to run `String#match` or `RegExp#exec` explicitly, `String#replace` does it under the hood.

You can use

```js
let string = "\nTitle: Hello World\nAuthors: Michael Dan\n"
console.log(string.replace(/(Title:).*(?=\nAuthors:)/g, '$1 Test'));
```

The pattern matches

- `(Title:)` - Group 1: `Title:` fixed string
- `.*` - the rest of the line, any zero or more chars other than line break chars, CR and LF (we need to consume this text in order to remove it)
- `(?=\nAuthors:)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with an LF char and `Authors:` string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oyk4VO/2).

If there can be a CRLF line ending in your string, you will need to replace `(?=\nAuthors:)` with `(?=\r?\nAuthors:)` or `(?=(?:\r\n?|\n)Authors:)`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off converting to an object first and then just defining the title property:

```
let string = 
`
Title: Hello World
Authors: Michael Dan
`

const stringLines = string.split('\n');
let stringAsObject = {};

stringLines.forEach(
  (line) => {
    if (line.includes(':')) {
      stringAsObject[line.split(':')[0]] = line.split(':')[1];
    }
  }
);

stringAsObject.Title = 'NewValue';
```

Comment: I don't have access to the `Hello World`. I need to find it first.

Comment: In that case, if you know that your properties are always separated by newlines and `:` characters you might be better off converting to a keyed object and then replacing your title

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` method like that:

```
string.replace("Hello World", "Test");
```

Comment: I don't have access to the `Hello World`  I need to find it first.

Comment: I don't get it, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/5gdbn6sf/2/

Comment: I'm saying I can't hardcode `Hello world`. I need to find it first and then replace it. This text is always different.

Answer (score 0):

I can achieve this without regex. All you need is knowing the index of the string that you need to find.

```js
var original = `
Title: Hello World
Authors: Michael Dan
`;

var stringToFind = "Hello World";
var indexOf = original.indexOf(stringToFind);
original = original.replace(original.substring(indexOf, indexOf + stringToFind.length), "Hey Universe!");

console.log(original)
```